Not able to send sign create request Box API
I am developing an application using the Box Sign API and encountering a persistent 404 Not Found error when attempting to create a sign request.
API Endpoint:

URL: https://api.box.com/2.0/sign_requests
HTTP Method: POST
Access Token: Full-authorization

Payload Sent:
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "role": "signer",
            "email": "y.alali@sened.ngo"
        }
    ],
    "source_files": [
        {
            "type": "file",
            "id": "1611107706949"
        }
    ],
    "parent_folder": {
        "type": "folder",
        "id": "278098710623"
    },
    "is_document_preparation_needed": true
}

Response Received:
{
    "type": "error",
    "code": "not_found",
    "status": 404,
    "message": "Not found",
    "help_url": "https://developer.box.com/guides/api-calls/permissions-and-errors/common-errors/",
    "request_id": "0e33bee75ee29cf32c3c2aefc0b0b7adb",
    "context_info": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "name": "Not Found",
                "message": "Not Found",
                "reason": "not_found"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Steps Taken:

Verified the existence and accessibility of the file and parent folder.
Confirmed that the access token has the necessary permissions and scopes.
Ensured the user associated with the access token has collaborator access to the file and folder.

Despite these steps, the error persists.
Additional Information:

The file ID 1611107706949 exists and is accessible.
The parent folder ID 278098710623 exists and is accessible.
The access token is fully authorized with the necessary scopes.
The user associated with the access token has the required permissions.

Question:
Could you please help me identify any additional requirements or configurations needed to successfully create a sign request using the Box Sign API?
References:

Box API Error Codes

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

everything seems correct.  try removing the parent_folder attribute all together and see if it will post into a default folder.  When this value is not passed in when the signature request, then we will use a default folder which is either the parent folder of the first source file in the payload if we have the permission to upload to that folder or a folder called "My Sign Requests".
